# Capitalizing first letter of text within array

Tags: javascript, capitalization

We're trying to split up a string of multiple words into an array of individual words. We want to capitalize each individual string within the array.

```
var titleCase = function(txt) {
  var words = txt.split(" ");
  words.forEach(function(words) {
  if (words === "the" || words === "and") { 
    return words; 
  } else  {
    return words.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words.slice(1);
  };
};
```

Comment: Elaborate. Specifically, what isn't working correctly?

Comment: Please mark the response that works for you as the answer by clicking the check mark next to the response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several syntax errors, and incorrect usage of the `Array.forEach` method here.  Try the following:

```
var titleCase = function(txt) {
  var words = txt.split(" ");
  words.forEach(function(word, idx, array) {
    if (word === "the" || word === "and") { 
      array[idx] = word; 
    } else  {
      array[idx] = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1);
    }
  });
  return words.join(" ");
};

console.log(titleCase("This is the test"));
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7Za7z/)

Comment: Thanks! that did work. But what exactly does the idx do?

Comment: Glad to help. The `idx` variable is the index of the current item in the array.  Please mark as answer if it works for you, thanks.